# Comparing timestamp to date in Python SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have an API in *Python* using *sqlalchemy*.

I have a string which represents a date in ISO format. I convert it using `datetime.strptime` like so: `datetime.strptime(ToActionDateTime, '%Y-%m-%dZ')`.

Now I have to compare the value of a table's column which is a `timestamp` to that date.
After converting the initial ISO string, an example result looks like this `2018-12-06 00:00:00`. I have to compare it for equality depending on date and not time but I can't manage to get it right. Any help would be appreciated.

Sample Python code:

```
ToActionDateTimeObj = datetime.strptime(ToActionDateTime, '%Y-%m-%dZ')
query = query.filter(db.c.Audit.ActionDateTime <= ToActionDateTimeObj)
```

**Edit:**

I have also tried to implement `cast` to both parts of the equation but it does not work either. I can't manage to get the right result when the selected date matches the date of the timestamp.

```
  from sqlalchemy import Date, cast
  ToActionDateTimeObj = datetime.strptime(ToActionDateTime, '%Y-%m-%dZ')
  query = query.filter(cast(db.c.Audit.ActionDateTime, Date) <= cast(ToActionDateTimeObj, Date))
```

Comment: I had already tried `cast` sorry for forgetting to mention it. It does not work. I also tried to cast both the column and the object, if I print the casted object what I'm getting is `CAST(:param_1 AS DATE)`

Comment: Post updated. I can't see why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using Oracle. My first thought was to increment by 1 day but I got asked by my supervisor to not use that walkaround.

Comment: When I cast the timestamp in Oracle SQL Developer it returns just the date like '11-NOV-2018'.

Comment: It throws this: `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01899: bad precision specifier`
But I don't want to compare only the day. I need to compare the whole date.

Comment: I'm hitting rock bottom here. I'm considering using `to_date` inside `to_char` inside `to_number` and compare them as numbers but it seems a little bit over the top..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Oracle [`DATE` datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B) actually stores both date and time, a cast to `DATE` will not rid the value of its time portion, as it would in most other DBMS. Instead the function [`TRUNC(date [, fmt])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79) can be used to reduce a value to its date portion only. In its single argument form it truncates to the nearest day, or in other words uses `'DD'` as the default model:

```
ToActionDateObj = datetime.strptime(ToActionDateTime, '%Y-%m-%dZ').date()
...
query = query.filter(func.trunc(db.c.Audit.ActionDateTime) <= ToActionDateObj)
```

If using the 2-argument form, then the [precision specifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html#GUID-8E10AB76-21DA-490F-A389-023B648DDEF8) for day precision is either `'DDD'`, `'DD'`, or `'J'`.

But this solution hides the column `ActionDateTime` from possible indexes. To make the query index friendly increment the date `ToActionDateObj` by one day and use less than comparison:

```
ToActionDateObj = datetime.strptime(ToActionDateTime, '%Y-%m-%dZ').date()
ToActionDateObj += timedelta(days=1)
...
query = query.filter(db.c.Audit.ActionDateTime < ToActionDateObj)
```

Comment: I got asked to avoid incrementing by one day. I managed to solve the issue, I just have to wait two days before marking the question as answered, you can take a look at it.

Comment: It'd be interesting to hear why you got asked, since it is the proper solution, if you want to use an existing index on `ActionDateTime`, as opposed to creating a function-based index. Your own solution suffers from the same, i.e. the column is hidden from possible existing indexes. Also you should not really (man)handle dates/datetimes as text, especially when proper methods such as `TRUNC()` exist.

Comment: I don't know why I got asked to do so, my first thought was to increment by one day but since this got turned down I had to find another way. I appreciate your reply, you really filled me in about things I didn't take into consideration, I used your first solution since it's better than mine and missing indexes does not affect the functionality I'm aiming for.